# Why do the Bootstrap 4 elements reload entire Angular 7 application?

Tags: css, angular, web, bootstrap-4

I am working with bootstrap 4 and angular 7, I have the following element, which function is to hide/show a sidebar.

```
<a
  class="app-sidebar__toggle"
  href="#"
  data-toggle="sidebar"
  aria-label="Hide Sidebar"
></a>
```

The problem is when I enter to specific route, this reloads all page. These are my routes in app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'catalogo/lista', component: CatalogoListaComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

So, if I enter to http://localhost:4200/home, the error will happen, but if I enter to any other route (my default empty route will redirect to /home), for example, http://localhost:4200 or http://localhost:4200/a_route_that_not_exists, I am redirected to /home (as expected), and the button that show/hide the sidebar works well.

I hope to be clear in my problem and I would like a lot you can help me.

EDIT: More code of my application...

This is my app.component.html:

```
<app-header></app-header>

<app-sidebar></app-sidebar>

<div class="app-content">
  <app-title [titulo]="titulo" [icono]="icono [breadcrumbs]="breadcrumbs"></app-title>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

This is my header.component.html (where I use the link to show/hide the sidebar):

```
<header class="app-header">
  <a class="app-header__logo" href="index.html">Vali</a>
  <!-- Sidebar toggle button-->
  <a
    class="app-sidebar__toggle"
    href="#"
    data-toggle="sidebar"
    aria-label="Hide Sidebar"
  ></a>
  <p>.... more html</p>
</header>
```

And this is my sidebar.component.html:

```
<div class="app-sidebar__overlay" data-toggle="sidebar"></div>
<aside class="app-sidebar">
  <div class="app-sidebar__user">
    <img
      class="app-sidebar__user-avatar"
      src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/jsa/48.jpg"
      alt="User Image"
    />
    <div>
      <p class="app-sidebar__user-name">John Doe</p>
      <p class="app-sidebar__user-designation">Frontend Developer</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <ul class="app-menu">
    <li>
      <a class="app-menu__item" [routerLink]="['/home']">
        <i class="app-menu__icon fa fa-home"></i>
        <span class="app-menu__label">Inicio</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    more menu elements...
  <ul>
</aside>
```

Comment: How are you navigating to the `catalogo/lista` route? Are you using a [routerLink] directive in the page? Also (just to double check), is your sidebar outside your `<router-outlet>` element?

Comment: Yes, I am using [routerLink] to access my routes, and the siderbar is outside <router-outlet>, the problem is only when I enter the full url in the browser, for example http://localhost:4200/catalogo/lista or http://localhost:4200/home. If I enter to the route http://localhost:4200, or any other route that not exists, I am redirected to home and the application works well

Comment: EDIT: Just saw your edit, I understand what's happening better now! Does the page not load properly when you enter a direct URL? Or is some other component not loading properly?

Comment: The page and the components loads well, but when I click the button that shows/hide the sidebar (the <a> element in the beginning of my question), the page is reloaded (try to go to # in href), instead of showing/hiding the sidebar

Comment: With the presence of the `href="#"`, clicking the `a` element will always trigger a routing action. Does removing the href break the bootstrap action? If it does you can almost certainly recreate it in Angular. If you provide some general component code (showing the component housing the sidebar and `a` element) I can show you how to accomplish this!

Comment: See my edits, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally a lot of the Popper/ JS elements in Bootstrap won't work out of the box in Angular; Angular provides a pretty solid way to handle elements like sidenavs.

Since the element you want to use to toggle the sidenav doesn't exist in the same component as the sidenav, you can set up a basic service that handles the sidenav state. To create your sidenav service (run in console in your project root):

```
ng g s sidenav
```

And then in the generated sidenav.service.ts:

```js
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class SidenavService {
  public isOpen: boolean = false;
  public toggleChange: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  constructor() {}

  public toggle(): void {
    this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
    this.toggleChange.next(this.isOpen);
  }
}
```

In your `header.component.html` you can modify the clickable element that will show/ hide the sidebar:

```
<a
  class="app-sidebar__toggle"
  aria-label="Hide Sidebar"
  (click)="toggleSidebar()"
></a>
```

In your `header.component.ts` file you can then set `toggleSidebar()` to run the `toggle()` function in the service you just set up:

```js
import {SidenavService} from "[wherever your service is located]";


@Component({ /*...*/ })
export class HeaderComponent {

  constructor(private sidenavService: SidenavService)

  toggleSidebar(): void {
    this.sidenavService.toggle();
  }

}
```

You can then (in either your app component or sidebar component) set up reacting to the toggle:

```js
//assuming you're in sidebar.component.ts
import {SidenavService} from "[wherever your service is located]";
import {OnInit, OnDestroy} from "@angular/core";
import {Subscription} from "rxjs";

@Component({ /*...*/ })
export class SidebarComponent implement OnInit, OnDestroy {
  isOpen: boolean;
  sidenavSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private sidenavService: SidenavService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sidenavSubscription = this.sidenavService.toggleChange.subscribe(isOpenChange => {
      this.isOpen = isOpenChange;
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sidenavSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

You can then use the `isOpen` variable in your sidebar component in different ways to control sidebar activity. Examples include using an `[ngClass]` directive:

```html
<!--in your header component-->
<header [ngClass]={'active': isOpen, 'inactive': !isOpen} >
</header>
```

Or you can build in something using angular animations to animate the sidebar in and out (using `ngIf` and the `:enter`/ `:leave` transitions).

Comment: Thanks a lot. The problem was the javascript/jquery code in the original bootstrap template, it was trying to access elements that were not loaded yet. Now, translating it to angular components and services, my application works well.